# Endpoint to security gateway tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, android, tap, tun

I want to establish a connection between the client and the proxy server through a VPN tunnel in android device.
I want to do this at layer 2 or 3 , where a packet can captured and encrypted.

Please suggest any way to establish the connection. As far as now I found that tun/tap but they can only be done on rooted device ( please correct me if I am wrong) .

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is also linux environment. In android by default use tun adapter for vpn connection. Your android not need rooted to use vpn with tun adapter. Use openvpn client, you can config with your own custom server. But there is any commercial apps, they say support tap adapter, may be it need rooted for install tap adapter driver.